# Multiple Subnet, Same Gateway

Tags: vlan, subnet, gateway, static-routes

I have a nexus3000 switch that has a L3 connection with an uplink switch. (`172.18.186.129-130/30`) ...

In downlink, I have multiple servers and VLANs and I have a range of IP-addresses (`172.18.186.0/25`) which I want to subnet and use in my network.

My concern is how can I have multiple subnets without having multiple gateways for each subnet. Currently I set an `172.18.186.1/25` to int VLAN 1 as a gateway for the whole range, however if I use /26 /27 etc ranges I cannot use the same gateway to route the traffic to my uplink and vice versa.

Any suggestion for this scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need a separate SVI gateway for each subnet. You should not use 172.18.186.1/25 on SVI VLAN 1, rather 172.18.186.1/[Mask] whether that is a /26, a /27 or whatever you use for that subnet.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid (having separate gateway for each subnet) ... Did you mean that I need to create multiple VLANs and set multiple SVI (per VLAN) in order to use each subnet?

Comment: That or you need to use secondary IP addresses on the SVI VLAN 1. But end result is that you need a gateway on each subnet.